# What unequal probability sampling methods exist for weights which are extremely different from each other?

Tags: sampling, algorithms

Suppose I have $N$ samples, each having a relative weight of $w_1, \ldots, w_N$. Assume that the largest weight is $10,000$, while the smallest weight is just $1$.

Suppose I wanted to get $m\leq N$ samples. If we were to sample this by weighted sampling, such that the largest weight is 10000x more likely to be chosen than the rest, we would almost always get the sample corresponding to the largest weight.

Are there methods which exist for dealing with extreme weight sampling problems that can maximize the Effective Sample Size?

**EDIT:** For example, I have heard of methods such as weight trimming, etc. Is there a part of the literature which deals with this?

Comment: `we would certainly almost always get the sample corresponding to the largest weight, and never get the smallest weight` why? how?

Comment: No, with SRS, you'd have equal probability of selecting all samples.

Comment: sorry, I meant a weighted sampling scheme where the inclusion probability is proportional to the weights.

Comment: I don't understand - the problem is that weighted random sampling is more likely to sample items with higher weights? How is that a problem?

Comment: @RyanVolpi I am in a scenario where I need to sample other elements as well, and having such a large weight makes it so that my sample size is effectively 1 at worst.

Comment: This question is presently too vague and open-ended for this site, because (a) there is a huge number of possible solutions and (b) they depend on what kind of analysis you intend to do with the sample.  Please clarify what your specific scenario is.

Comment: *"Suppose I have N samples ... Suppose I wanted to get m≤N samples ... maximize the Effective Sample Size"* It is unclear how you are gonna make this shift from N samples to m samples. How, why, when, where does this happen? What is the situation? What do you mean by 'weights'? What is the point/goal of the sampling, why does it make that you care about the weights? What do you mean by 'effective sample size'? Effective in relation to what function that is dependent on sample size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to a problem in finance / stock index arbitrage, where one may want to "sample" a small number of assets in a large portfolio to estimate (or "track") the performance (weighted investment return) of a larger portfolio. E.g., "track" the performance of a 1000 stock portfolio with a 50 stock portfolio.

This problem is "easy" if $m=N$, "sample" every case.

With $m<N$, one approach that works pretty well in practice but is not provably optimal (with the method described below) is to sample using the [inverse cumulative distribution method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling); and to consider two phases.

Sort the cases by declining weight.
In the *first phase*, select immediately all cases (stocks) with weight exceeding what you hope to represent in the remaining samples, for instance at first iteration, select the largest weighted case if $w_1 \ge \frac{1}{m}$. At the second iteration select the largest remaining case if $w_2 \ge \frac{1-w_1}{m-1}$    $\ldots$

When $w_{J+1} < \frac{1-\sum\limits_1^J w_j}{m-J}$, in *phase two*, sample $m-J$ cases identified by samples from the uniform distribution over the interval $\textrm{U}\left(\sum\limits_1^J w_j,1\right)$ and the inverse cumulative distribution function.

When constructing a parameter estimate (e.g., portfolio return), use the exact weights $w_1 \ldots w_J$ for the large weight cases, and use the average residual weight $\tilde{w}=\frac{1-\sum\limits_1^J w_j}{m-J}$ for the sampled smaller cases. For example $\hat{\mu}_x = \sum\limits_1^J \left(w_j x_j\right) + \sum\limits_{J+1}^{m}\left(\tilde{w} x_j\right)$.

A final "trick" to consider with $K$ multiple samples of size $m$ is to use [antithetic variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates) when selecting $m-J$ uniform variates for the smaller weighted cases in the distinct $K$ repeats.

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you know if the approach with the two phases you described has a name and if there is literature for it? I am wondering what the effective sample size would be for the procedure and if it is maximized in a sense? Thanks

Comment: The algorithm was published in: Keane, Kevin R. A passive approach to a passive strategy. Goldman Sachs & Co, Stock Index Research (~1988). The "trick" was published in Keane, Kevin R.  Complementary portfolios. Goldman Sachs & Co, Stock Index Research (~1988). I'm away from my paper files for another week or so, I'll see if I can post scans of the documents to ResearchGate when I return.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the performance of this sampling strategy in a simulation with a toy dataset. Does someone give it a try and post the code? Given a certain set of values and weights (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 with weights 1000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1). How well do samples drawn with the above strategy reproduce the expected mean of approximately 1.0449595 and what is the standard deviation of the estimated mean if we make use of the above strategy? How does the the number of drawn samples $m$ affect the outcome of the simulation?

Comment: @krkeane It would be great to get scans of the documents. Was the paper based on any existing research or was it completely novel?

Comment: I learned the general skill set from https://ieor.berkeley.edu/people/lee-w-schruben/ in a digital systems simulation class (in the dark ages, in FORTRAN).  The book was an early edition of Law, Averill M., W. David Kelton, and W. David Kelton. "Simulation modeling and analysis". Inverse cumulative distribution method is a technique for simulating arbitrary distributions, probably in the book.  Antithetic variates is a bit more esoteric.  Samples are NOT random but pseudo-random, so manipulating the "random sampling" permits samples as different as possible. E.g., u1~U(0,1); u2=1-u1.

Comment: @user321627 : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363279135_A_passive_approach_to_a_passive_strategy and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363279243_Complementary_portfolios .  The second paper does not appear to explain much. To construct negatively correlated "samples", sample far apart as possibl, step through the inverse cumulative distribution function at equal intervals.  For two samples, use equal space percentiles.  Eg, in sample 1: .85, .86, .87 ...; in sample 2: .855, .865, .875 ....  For three samples, in 1: .85, .86 ... ;  in 2: .8533, .8633 ...; in 3: .8567, .8667 ....

Comment: @krkeane Thanks so much for this, this was very much what I was hoping to learn about.

Answer (score 3):

For Monte Carlo Simulations, there is a whole branch of research dealing with what is called "rare event sampling". Rare events are events which have low chance to occur (or in your language "have a small weight").

In computational physics and computational chemistry, [rare event sampling techniques](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare_event_sampling) are employed to sample states from the state space which are otherwise not accessible within reasonable amount of compute time. Those rare states may be needed to compute highly accurate estimates of ensemble averages. An ensemble average could be highly biased if a free energy barrier would otherwise prevent the system from exploring the whole state space.

The most obvious example of a physical system requiring a rare event system to be correctly simulated is a system with two stable states of equal energy which are connected by a pathway which requires very high energy. If the system starts in one energy minimum it is unlikely to see the other energy minimum within a reasonable amount of Monte Carlo steps.

One way to overcome this issue is for example Wang-Landau sampling. You can find the implementation details in the [corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_and_Landau_algorithm).
The essence of the algorithm is to iteratively reduce the weights for states which you already visited so that it is not revisited so frequently again (while additionally keeping track of the way the weights were modified for each state - this will later provide you with a reweighing factor). In your case, a state would be a unique sample and the ratio $\frac{g(\boldsymbol{r}'\rightarrow \boldsymbol{r})}{g(\boldsymbol{r}\rightarrow \boldsymbol{r}')}$ is given by the ratio of weights e.g. 1000/1.

A simulation could then evolve like this:

1. draw a sample according to the initial weighs
2. Maintain the Wang landau histogram S
3. Transition to a new sample with the Wang-Landau acceptance probability (which punishes states already visited)

(Repeat steps 2 and 3 many times).

This will result in drawing all the samples of within your sample space. If you want to compute e.g. a simple averages from these enforced samples, then you need to perform a reweighing:

$E[X] = \frac{\sum_i \exp(S_i) x_i}{\sum_i \exp(S_i)},$

where $i$ indexes unique samples and $x_i$ is their value. $S_i$ is the corresponding value of the Wang-Landau histogram which is a result of the MC simulation.

Other methods like Metadynamics are essentially equivalent to Wang-Landau sampling. The wikipedia entry on meta dynamics contains a [nice video](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadynamics) illustrating the iterative punishment of already visited states (along a potentially binned collective variable used for defining states in a continuous interval). Intuitively the biasing Potential modiefies the underlying energy landscape (and therefore the "weights" of the sates) forcing the simulation to explore new states.

Comment: This is a nice explanation of some sort of sampling involving weights, but the question seems to be limited to a case *"Suppose I wanted to get m≤N samples"*. How does the answer relate to that?

Comment: Given $N$ samples which have $k\leq N$ unique states, then Wang-Landau resampling will allow to observe exactly $k\leq N$ different states (samples) from which an accurate estimate for an observable (e.g. a mean value) can be computed. These biasing techniques may also be use in reinforcement learning and the like. https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/21/7780 This might however go beyond the scope of the question and referencing it here is speculative.

Answer (score 1):

If using weighted random sampling (the $w$'s being weights) then this behavior is completely understandable, a sample with weight 1 will almost never be present in a random sample if max weight is say 10000 (and assuming the other weights are more or less uniformly distributed between the min and max).

Two options with no guarantees come to mind, 1) use some sort of transformation for the weights, e.g. sqrt(weights), 2) replace the weights with... ranks (especially useful if you have outliers).

Comment: What would transforming the weights accomplish??  I suspect there might be some radically different interpretations of the term "weight" possible for this thread, so it would help to explain what you understand it to mean and what role it would play in sampling.

Comment: @whuber OP stated that these weights are to be used for weighted sampling, however some of these weights are "extreme" and OP additionally asks for `a weighted sampling scheme where the inclusion probability is proportional to the weights`. Hence why I proposed the transformation, which would decrease the influence of big weights.

Comment: But that transformation would alter the weights!  As a result, *any analysis of the data has to be modified accordingly.*  You neither mention that nor provide a solution.